# Why is iPhone 6 and above wkwebview not accepting taps on the bottom?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, navigation, wkwebview

I noticed this with separate html code, but I can repeat the same issue using the following url example of an html web app view, such as would be used in a hybrid app. To make it easiest for someone reading this to reproduce the issue, I will include that url here (I don't need to use that url. I have my own code. But this url does the same thing, so is a good example for someone reading this to examine.)

https://framework7.io/examples/tab-bar

[Image: These bottom nav bar items do not respond to touch on iPhone 6s or 6s Plus, but DO work on 5s and SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQVtF.jpg)

To reproduce:

1. Create a simple iOS App with a wkwebview (you may already have one from a previous project)
2. Simply ensure the webview loads the above url, and you will be able to observe the issue.

If a wkwebview in a Swift app loads the above url in an iPhone 5s or lower within a full screen wkwebview, the bottom tab menu (with choices for information, inbox, upload, and photos) will work. But if opened in iPhone 6s or 6s Plus, the bottom tab menu will not work. You can tap on choices, and nothing will happen.

Important: This is not in Safari. This happens in the context the link being opened in a wkwebview within a Swift app. This is repeatable.

I have checked the layer debugger, and nothing is in the way of the bottom tab.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried on iOS 10 it is working. Which version are you running.

Comment: Thanks, @New16. I tried it on iOS 10, as well as 8.1 and 8.2.  I tried it on three different iPhones as well. Identical results in physical devices AND simulator.  Specifically: Not in Safari, but in a WKWebView in a Swift project.  In iPhone 6s and 6s Plus, the bottom tab buttons do not work, but in iPhone 5s and SE the buttons do work.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to just delete this, but you never know. Someone else may have the same question later. Maybe this will help them.

So here is the answer which I have just figured out:

I hadn't added auto constraints to ensure the webview would stay the same size as the window. That is why it worked on the smaller phones like the 5s and SE (because the webview happened to aready be big enough.)  Meanwhile, the bigger screens of the 6s and 6s Plus were beyond the size of the webview.

I saw it in storyboard and added constraints to ensure the webview would stretch to however big the screen was, and everything started working. The lower nav bar was no longer out of reach of my taps.

I do think it's odd that the content displayed on the entire screen, but only the area which detected touches did not extend to the screen, but that is an opportunity for me to examine the code and see how things are arranged.

The main issue has been solved.

Comment: I think the HTML5 renders the WebPage according to the device screen size. Thats why you are able to see the WebPage properly, I added the WKWebView programatically. So, I didn't see any issue.

Comment: Cheers for this!